# Set all "✔" symbols to green, and all "✘" symbols to red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building one of those html tables comparing different pricing options and the features they contain, for example:

```
<table>
<tr><th></th><th>free</th><th>lite</th></tr>
<tr><th>Example feature</th><th>✘</th><th>✔</th>
</table>
```

I'd like to try all ticks in green, and all checks in red. I thought the best way to do this might be using an onload in javascript or jquery, to set all css properties depending on the symbol found in each table cell.

Would this be the most efficient way of doing this? If so, could someone provide guidance on how I could:

1. Recognize each occurrence of a specific symbol on the page.
2. Set the CSS property for each of this occurrence when the page loads.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would go with giving the `th` class names like `checkmark` and `cross` and target those with css.

Comment: "_Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work**, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Comment: Right, and I would even use the `content` CSS property in order to inject the ticks into the cell.

Comment: On a side-note: Don't abuse the `th` tag. It's a table head tag, so you should only use it in the head of a table (e.g. the section that describes what each column means). Use `td` for normal table cells instead. Use CSS if you want to style them like the th tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Sumurai8, not sure why I used it in my example above. I can assure you td was used for normal cells. Still getting the hang of tables! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery for this, but I don't see any good reason to, unless you want to change something dynamically later on.  You can set the class of each element that has an x or check in it, and just use plain old CSS.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><th></th><th>free</th><th>lite</th></tr>
<tr><th>Example feature</th><th class="x">✘</th><th class="check">✔</th>
</table>
```

```
.x {
    color: red;
}

.check {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set it like you would set the color on any element, target it with something and set the color with `css()`

```
$('th:contains(✘)').css('color','red');
$('th:contains(✔)').css('color','green');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMLQf/)

or

```
$('th').css('color', function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('✘') != -1 ? 'red' : 
           $(this).text().indexOf('✔') != -1 ? 'green' : '';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMLQf/1/)

Comment: +1 contains selector, did not know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing ✘, write

```
<span class='x-highlight'>✘</span>
```

Or afterwards,

```
html = html.replace("✘", "<span class='x'>✘</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zg4e/1/) I created. This can be done with simple CSS but you requested to use jQuery/JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>free</th>
        <th>lite</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Example feature</th>
        <th class="cross">✘</th>
        <th class="check">✔</th>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cross').css('color', 'red');
    $('.check').css('color', 'green');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a green image for the tick and red image for the check...No need to get complicated here :)

If you don't want to do that then just do a class="cross", class="check" on the `<th>` enclosing the check or cross and then set the text colour appropriately in that class...or you can even do it in the style directly.